# Video not play Samsung Android mobile phone or the Barnes & Noble Nook Tablet

Tags: android, jwplayer, samsung-mobile

I have problem to view video on Samsung Android mobile phone or the Barnes & Noble Nook Tablet.

My code is below.

```
<div id='mediaspace'>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("mediaspace").setup({
            'file': "1.mp4",
            'width': $('[data-role="content"]').width(),
            'height': $(window).height() - 100,
            'autostart': 'true',
            'stretching': 'exactfit',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            modes: [
            {type: 'html5'},
            {type: 'flash', src: 'player.swf'}

        ],
            'allowfullscreen':"true",
            events:{
                onComplete:function()
                    {
                        jwplayer("mediaspace").setFullscreen(false)
                    }   
            }

    });
</script>
```

in Browser every thing is fine I have tested on Firefox, Safari and Chrome Browsers but in android tablet and phone it shows error "Cannot play video Sorry, this video cannot be played." 
http://i8ecoders.com/adnan/igrappling/
this is Live link of my Site.